# What does this mean? [SPOILER ALERT, Spiderman no way home]

Tags: meaning-in-context

**Forget me knots**

This is the name of a song that was used in a scene of Spiderman No Way Home.

[Here is a link to the sound track.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36IHX306qeg)

It was used in the scene where all of Spiderman's closest friends and family forget him.

I can understand "forget" and "me" but not "knots."

What does "Forget me knots" mean in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a pun.

**Forget-me-not** (without the k) is a name for a type of flowering plant, and **forget me not** is a [pretty common melodramatic phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forget_me_not_(disambiguation)), literally meaning "Don't forget me".

I don't know the Spiderman context, but I'm guessing the use of "knots" instead of "nots" is wordplay, to do with Spiderman's ability to create sticky threads that might form knots?

Comment: You are correct. I am very familiar with the context and it is wordplay on the phrase "forget me not." Spiderman is sad that his closest friends/family are going to forget him hence the emotional sound track and the behind-the-scenes pun.